# Autocomplete deletes last character from words sometimes

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a custom command `define` that gets words definition from dictionary. I wanted to make an autocomplete script to complete the words I want to define using the list of words found in `/usr/share/dict/words`. This is what I have so far:

**Autocomplete script: /etc/bash_completion.d/define**

```
_define()
{
    dict='/usr/share/dict/words'
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    regex="^$cur*"
    words=$(grep $regex $dict)

    if [[ $cur != -* ]]
    then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$(echo $words)" $cur) )
    else
        COMPREPLY=()
    fi
    return 0
}

complete -F _define define
```

When I hit `[tab][tab]` sometimes I get a list of words begining with the typed word, other times it just deletes the last character. For example when I do `define wall [tab][tab]` I get `define wal`, but if I do `define wal [tab][tab]` I get a list of words.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be something to do with single quote characters in the completion words list `'`, I fixed it by changing `grep` command's regex from `^$cur*` to `^$cur[^']*$`:

```
_define()
{
    local dict='/usr/share/dict/words'
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local regex="^$cur[^']*$"

    if [[ $cur == -* ]]
    then
        COMPREPLY=()
    else
        local WORDS="$( grep "$regex" $dict )"
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${WORDS}" -- $cur) )
    fi
}

complete -F _define define
```